# Issue using awaitable and self made async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

Why does a method returning a `Task` does not get executed when returning it's instance. I thought this must happen, because `await`ing the method/delegate would
put it into some *queue* and later execute the resulting task.

So why does this `Task` never gets executed when calling `Do()`?

```
public void Do()
{
    SomeTask().Wait()
}

public async Task SomeTask()
{
    return new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World!") });
}
```

**EDIT**

Or do I alwas need `await Task.Run(...)`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a `Task` but never starting it, so it's impossible for it to complete.

Use `Task.Run` to return a "hot" (started) `Task` instead:

```
return Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World!") });
```

Also, `async` keyword is unnecessary as you're not awaiting the created task.

Comment: Your last hint did it! Thank you! +1

Comment: With `async`, what's being returned is a `Task<Task>`.